# Whats is the formula in Excel to display A2 if A1 =1

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to display what is in cell A2 if A1 is `1`.  How do I do that?

Comment: You need the `IF()` function which takes three parameters: the criteria, the result on success and the result on failure, so you want `=if(A1=1,A2,"")` where `""` means an empty string (ie, display nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Write is A2 as below:

=IF(A1=1,"The text you Want to Display","")

in this case, A2 wil show "The text you Want to Display" if A1 has value 1.

---

A better approach to this is to include a 3rd cell e.g A3 that hold your value i.e "The text you Want to Display":

Then the contetents for cells hall be:

A1 :  1 ,
A2 :  =IF(A1=1,A3,"") ,
A3 :  The text you Want to Display

I hope it helps.